# Frequency Plot with 2 classes in R

Tags: r, plot, frequency

I have a dataframe with 2 features, the first one is the Classe 'Yes' or 'No', the second one is "JobSatisfaction". I want to plot something like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWzV1.png

Where I count the frequency of each value of the variable JobSatisfaction and I color the different classes.

[image source](https://www.kaggle.com/antoineli/imbalanced-dataset-about-employee-attrition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(your_data, aes(x = JobSatisfaction, fill = Class)) %>%
  geom_bar()
```

You can play with the `position` argument of `geom_bar()`, as [described here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html).